# Strange Linking error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, templates, reference, linker

I'm working on a big c++ project and change code from other people. During this I got a linker error stating that reference `VarA` is multiple defined. I found the corresponding variable and it had been defined in a cpp file which had directly been included into the project. I tried to convert the source file in a header file and a source file, which doesn't work.

I then tried to move the variable declaration into new separate h/cpp only containing this variable, which looks then like:

h-file (aaa.h)

```
#ifndef AAA_H
#define AAA_H

#include "classAdefinition.h"
extern ClassA VarA;

#endif
```

cpp-file (aaa.cpp)

```
#include "aaa.h"
ClassA VarA;
```

If I now include `aaa.h` in the main file, the linker error adds the new created `aaa.obj` to the error message (e.g. `VarA` is also defined there) which is exactly what I expected. But when I remove the definition of `VarA` in the main file I get a linker error staying that `VarA` is not defined, which is really confusing.

Does anyone have a clue what might be the cause of this behavior?

I'm using VS2008, and the project is created with `cmake`. Might this cause the problem? E.g. could there be a configuration issue? We also use templates quite often, can this lead to the problem?

Comment: When you remove "definition of `VarA` from main file", are you still linking `aaa.cpp` to the rest of the stuff?

Comment: I think so, but i'm not absolutly sure. As mentioned, we use cmake to build the programm. But i don't change the cmake-configuration when removing VarA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found the error, but the problem is now avoided because most of the third-party code has been changed and the error does no longer occure.

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove the multiple defined error which occurs because of multiple cyclic calls I suggest the first and foremost thing that you should do is to edit your header files to include the following macro (whatever it might be in your case) give each file a unique name

```
#ifndef CAR_HPP
#define CAR_HPP
class Car 
    {
    public:
    ....
    protected:
    ....
    };
#endif
```

Comment: I do have an inclusion guard in the file. Sorry, my fault i forgot to add it to the code above.